# Browsers randomly not requesting resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, error-handling

My website includes code to log JavaScript errors back to the web server (Apache) as they occur, using a combination of $exceptionHandler in AngularJS for exceptions within my Angular code and also via window.onerror for stuff happening outside of Angular.

A number of errors logged of late indicate that clients are seemingly randomly failing to request one resource or another. So far, I cannot find any correlation between the specific resource not being fetched, or the browser or client device exhibiting the issue.

As an example, one of the JavaScript resources on my pages is called 'utility.js'. This includes some global functions and other common stuff for the website. An iPhone user (on iOS 10.3.2) today loaded a page and fetched all of the resources for the page except utility.js (I reviewed the Apache access log for the session and could see all other resources identified in the page being requested - and in the correct order - but not utility.js, and there was nothing in the error log around the same timeframe). A second later, a JavaScript error was logged to our server from the phone on account of a global function defined in utility.js not being defined.

Another (more commonly occurring) example is that of AngularJS generating a [$compile:tpload](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload) error when attempting to access a HTML template resource. I get several of these each day. The template in question varies between instances of the error, but in the cases I have reviewed, again there is no evidence in the Apache log of a request for the template resource. Other template resources for the same page were loaded successfully. Of note in this case, I sometimes see the same client log the error regarding the same resource several times over a few minutes, suggesting the user is reloading the page and getting the same issue, so there does seem to be something 'stuck' or blocking in the browser, but I just cannot imagine what.

I'm reasonably confident that these resources are not cached in users' browsers already as in the cases I have looked at, other resources on the page were requested that would not have been if the page had already been loaded.

I really don't know where to go with this issue at present. To my knowledge, there is no way for me to get any visibility into the browser's network traffic for my page.

Any suggestions on how to further diagnose this issue?

Comment: is this only happening on phones?

Comment: No... most commonly with phones, but have observed on desktop clients also. I think IE11 has a particular penchant for it, but is not isolated

Comment: Let me revise that a little:  Majority Android + Chrome 58, but have observed on other devices/browsers/versions and on desktop clients also - so far IE11 and Chrome 58 on Windows 7 or Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the cause of (at least a significant portion of) the $compile:tpload errors, if not possibly also some others:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14219

Essentially, it seems Chrome and Firefox incorrectly(?) generate error events for XHR requests that are aborted due to unloading the page (ie. reloading it or navigating away). In my case, clients must have requests in-flight for the angular templates which are getting aborted when they reload or navigate away... perhaps they are on a slow network connection and having issues loading the page and so attempt a reload.

I reproduced the error by inserting a PHP sleep() request into one of the templates to prevent Apache from responding immediately. If I load the page, then reload it or navigate away, the $compile:tpload error is logged accordingly. I also found that Apache only logs requests in the access log file once they are responded to, which goes at least some way to explaining the behaviour I observed there (though not fully!)

It does not explain the incidents of the error occurring for IE11 though - I could not reproduce it with that. Nor does it explain why the vast majority of incidents are on Android devices.

In summary, some progress, but I don't have all the answers yet. At least this might be semi-useful to somebody out there!